# Angular filter multiple column implement with angular material chips

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material

I've done multiple column filtering using angular material datatable. When I tried to implement material chip on search text, that code doesn't work as used to. Here is my code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-2p4tjq)

- First filter working good as expected
- Second filter with material chip needs to be work same as filter 1
- Text turn to chip when press enter

app.html

```html
<div>
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of searchItems" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(item)">
        {{item.name}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input placeholder="Filter 2" matInput [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [formControl]="nameFilter" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

app.ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatTableDataSource
} from '@angular/material';
import {
  COMMA,
  TAB,
  SPACE,
  ENTER
} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {
  MatChipInputEvent
} from '@angular/material';
import {
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';


export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export interface SearchItem {
  name: string;
}


const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [{
    id: 999,
    name: 'test',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    name: '999',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Helium',
    weight: 4.0026,
    symbol: 'He'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Lithium',
    weight: 6.941,
    symbol: 'Li'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Beryllium',
    weight: 9.0122,
    symbol: 'Be'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Boron',
    weight: 10.811,
    symbol: 'B'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Carbon',
    weight: 12.0107,
    symbol: 'C'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Nitrogen',
    weight: 14.0067,
    symbol: 'N'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Oxygen',
    weight: 15.9994,
    symbol: 'O'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Fluorine',
    weight: 18.9984,
    symbol: 'F'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Neon',
    weight: 20.1797,
    symbol: 'Ne'
  },
];

/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  positionFilter = new FormControl();
  nameFilter = new FormControl();
  private filterValues = {
    id: '',
    name: ''
  }

  filteredValues = {
    position: '',
    name: '',
    weight: '',
    symbol: '',
    topFilter: false
  };

  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [COMMA, TAB, ENTER];
  searchItems: SearchItem[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.positionFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((positionFilterValue) => {
      console.log(positionFilterValue);

      this.filteredValues['position'] = positionFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
      this.filteredValues['topFilter'] = false;
    });


    this.nameFilter.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.filterValues['name'] = value
        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues)
      });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    console.log('event', event);

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.searchItems.push({
        name: value.trim()
      });
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  remove(item: SearchItem): void {
    const index = this.searchItems.indexOf(item);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.searchItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }


  // applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  //   let filter = {
  //     name: filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(),
  //     position: filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(),
  //     topFilter: true
  //   }
  //   this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(filter)
  // }

  createFilter() {
    let filterFunction = function(data: any, filter: string): boolean {
      let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter)
      let idSearch = data.id.toString().indexOf(searchTerms.id) != -1
      let nameSearch = () => {
        let found = false;
        searchTerms.name.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
          if (data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1) {
            found = true
          }
        });
        return found
      }
      return idSearch && nameSearch()
    }
    return filterFunction
  }
}
```

Anyone please let me know what I missed out?

Comment: Let me know if I'm right, I'm testing your stackblitz code, I think the problem (or almost one of the problem/s) is, when in the 2º input you write for example 'a' press enter, chip is made, the filter is correct, but if you delete the chip, the table still have the filter. Is it your problem?

Comment: @Kalamarico, the second input should work same as first input (multi column filter). If you search for 'a' <space> 'b', it should show 'a' and 'b' column. I just updated stackblitz. Here is links https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datatable-multi-column-filter-with-chip

Comment: Ok I see but tell me what is exactly the problem you have, as I said, the problem I'm seeing is when you delete a chip (in the second input) the filter is not updated and the table shows the same filtered results before deleting, right?